# Sqlite insert trigger on virtual table with condition

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-trigger

I am trying to insert on the virtual table only when the condition met to insert, like when the type is "-1" then only insert.

But it was inserting all the record

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists test_ai;

CREATE TRIGGER test_ai AFTER INSERT ON test 
WHEN new.type = -1
BEGIN INSERT INTO 
test_fts(body) VALUES (new.body); 
END;

/*Create table */
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `body` TEXT, `caption` TEXT, `type` INTEGER );

/*Create virtual table */
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE test_fts USING fts5(body, content=test, content_rowid=id);

/* Insert into test table*/
insert into test(body, caption, type) values("5", "",-6);
```

Answer (score 1):

It just *looks like* they're there, it's basically a virtual "copy" of the content table. However, only the rows inserted with the trigger will be returned in an FTS query. Try

```
SELECT * from test_fts where body MATCH '5'
```

It will *not* return the sample row. The trigger insert builds the FTS structure for the desired row(s).